# Cordova/Phonegap build fails to find HTML templates

Tags: html, angularjs, cordova

I'm building my angularjs application to Phonegap Android application. I have builded the project using Yeoman/Grunt and I get it to work on webserver after that, but When build with Cordova/Phonegap to Android .apk file and installed on device I get only this to console:

```
 GET file:///android_asset/www/app/_main/main.tpl.html net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

When I debug the application with Chrome android debugging and look the source it sohws index.html as empty (but it can be can it? Since it has to load the angularjs to try to get to the main template, and that happens in the index.html) and I can't find any of the other .html files from there.

```
\platforms\android\assets\www
```

In cordovas android project folder everything seems to be just as it's upposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out by myself. It was due to the folder name. 
    `"_main"`

So the '_' -character broke it. :)